# Apache nifi Rest Api Issue

Tags: apache-nifi, hdf

when I try running this below url into the browser, I am not getting a 404 response. can any one please guide me on this, as how to use it

Thanks.
http://localhost:8080/nifi/provenance/search-options

[apache nifi rest api issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN8Nj.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahmed,

Your query for search options is wrong.Please try below query.

http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/provenance/search-options

Comment: ok, thank you. Can you please guide me how to create a process group,processor using nifi rest api.

Comment: The UI uses the REST API exclusively to perform any action. If you open up your browsers dev tools, you should be able to see the requests in action. Most dev tools will even allow you to copy the requests as cUrl commands.

Comment: @Ahmed,If my answer work for you then accept it as answer it may helpful for anyone.Please follow Matt instructions this is easy to understand how rest api works in  NiFi for create a processgroup,processor ..etc.